# Create tar file that extracts only the files and doesn't create folder during extract

Tags: ubuntu, tar

I have a folder with files which I want to zip into a tar.gz file.  I am using the following command:

```
tar -czvf filename.tar.gz  foldername
```

Sure enough this creates the file `filename.tar.gz`.  However, when I unzip the tar file, by default it creates a folder `filename` and places all the files into the folder.

Can I avoid this folder creation when I create the tar file itself. I tried the following command but it doesn't work.

```
tar -czv filename.tar.gz  foldername
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

My current directory structure is as follows:

```
~/Test/foldername
```

The directory foldername has all the files that I want to zip. My codes are as follows:

```
cd Test
tar czvf filename.tar foldername/*
```

Comment: You can always `cd` before zipping

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to utilize the `-C` command line argument, as in the following:

```
tar czvf filename.tar.gz -C foldername .
```

Note the final `.`, which tells `tar` to include "this directory" after having `cd`-ed into `foldername` by virtue of the `-C foldername` argument.

You end up with names in the tar file starting with `./` instead of `foldername/`, and they thus unpack into the current working directory.

If on the other hand, you have a tar file with names like `foldername/X`, and you want to un-tar that without the first directory component, then the argument `--strip-components=1` is your friend. Thus, the untar command might be:

```
tar xzf filename.tar.gz --strip-components=1
```

By that argument, the first directory component of all path names are "stripped away" during the un-tar-ing. Check out `man tar` for all the details.

Comment: Ronnquist Thank you.  however, my question is about avoiding the folder that gets created when you unzip the tar file.  Can I avoid that and unpack the files directly into the directory.

Comment: Or, alternatively, cd into the directory and run `tar cvzf ../filename.tar.gz .`.

Comment: @popeye, yes; that's exactly what happens. The very same as what Johan suggests, but with only the `tar` program doing the `cd` (not the whole shell)